# error from bundle install (an error occured while installing mini_racer (0.6.2)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-5

I am trying `bundle install` on Mac OS Monterey 12.3.1, however I get the following error:

```
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/include/ruby-2.6.0/ruby/ruby.h:2602:20: note: expanded from macro 'rb_funcall'
        rb_funcallv(recv, mid, \
                          ^~~
60 warnings generated.
linking shared-object mini_racer_extension.bundle
clang: error: no such file or directory: '/Users/mahdi/.gem/gems/libv8-node-16.10.0.0-x86_64-darwin/vendor/v8/universal-darwin/libv8/obj/libv8_monolith.a'
make: *** [mini_racer_extension.bundle] Error 1

make failed, exit code 2

Gem files will remain installed in /Users/mahdi/.gem/gems/mini_racer-0.6.2 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/mahdi/.gem/extensions/universal-darwin-21/2.6.0/mini_racer-0.6.2/gem_make.out

  /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:95:in `run'
  /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:44:in `block in make'
  /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:36:in `each'
  /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:36:in `make'
  /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/ext/ext_conf_builder.rb:63:in `block in build'
  /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tempfile.rb:295:in `open'
  /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/ext/ext_conf_builder.rb:26:in `build'
  /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:164:in `build_extension'
  /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:198:in `block in build_extensions'
  /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:195:in `each'
  /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:195:in `build_extensions'
  /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/installer.rb:851:in `build_extensions'
  /Users/mahdi/.gem/gems/bundler-2.3.16/lib/bundler/rubygems_gem_installer.rb:71:in `build_extensions'
  /Users/mahdi/.gem/gems/bundler-2.3.16/lib/bundler/rubygems_gem_installer.rb:28:in `install'
  /Users/mahdi/.gem/gems/bundler-2.3.16/lib/bundler/source/rubygems.rb:207:in `install'
  /Users/mahdi/.gem/gems/bundler-2.3.16/lib/bundler/installer/gem_installer.rb:54:in `install'
  /Users/mahdi/.gem/gems/bundler-2.3.16/lib/bundler/installer/gem_installer.rb:16:in `install_from_spec'
  /Users/mahdi/.gem/gems/bundler-2.3.16/lib/bundler/installer/parallel_installer.rb:186:in `do_install'
  /Users/mahdi/.gem/gems/bundler-2.3.16/lib/bundler/installer/parallel_installer.rb:177:in `block in worker_pool'
  /Users/mahdi/.gem/gems/bundler-2.3.16/lib/bundler/worker.rb:62:in `apply_func'
  /Users/mahdi/.gem/gems/bundler-2.3.16/lib/bundler/worker.rb:57:in `block in process_queue'
  /Users/mahdi/.gem/gems/bundler-2.3.16/lib/bundler/worker.rb:54:in `loop'
  /Users/mahdi/.gem/gems/bundler-2.3.16/lib/bundler/worker.rb:54:in `process_queue'
  /Users/mahdi/.gem/gems/bundler-2.3.16/lib/bundler/worker.rb:91:in `block (2 levels) in create_threads'

An error occurred while installing mini_racer (0.6.2), and Bundler cannot continue.

In Gemfile:
  mini_racer
```

Then, I have also tried `gem install mini_racer`, However I get this error

```
Building native extensions. This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing mini_racer:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/include/ruby-2.6.0/ruby/ruby.h:2602:20: note: expanded from macro 'rb_funcall'
        rb_funcallv(recv, mid, \
                          ^~~
60 warnings generated.
linking shared-object mini_racer_extension.bundle
clang: error: no such file or directory: '/Users/mahdi/.gem/gems/libv8-node-16.10.0.0-x86_64-darwin/vendor/v8/universal-darwin/libv8/obj/libv8_monolith.a'
make: *** [mini_racer_extension.bundle] Error 1

make failed, exit code 2

Gem files will remain installed in /Users/mahdi/.gem/gems/mini_racer-0.6.2 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/mahdi/.gem/extensions/universal-darwin-21/2.6.0/mini_racer-0.6.2/gem_make.out
```

I have also tried specifying the mini_racer version in Gemfile but that did not help.
Any suggestions that may help? Thanks

Comment: Try directly making changes in gemlock file. 
`mini_racer (0.4.0)
      libv8-node (~> 15.14.0.0)
`

downgrade mini-racer to - 0.4.0 and Remove libv8 and replace with libv8-node in gemlock file, mini-racer dependency tree

Comment: Same question here. Have you figured out how to solve it?